# Copy Paste outlook 2007 html body into a Word file

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word

I'm new to outlook VBA manipulation and therefore struggling with this task.
What would be the easiest way to copy the html body of the selected mail and paste it into a word file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Outlook object model provides three main ways for working with item bodies:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx).
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx).
3. The Word editor. The [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Word Document which represents the message body. So, **you can use the Word object model do whatever you need with the message body**. The Copy and Paste methods of the Document will do the trick.

See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for more information.